# Incorrect Oracle host

Tags: oracle, hostname, oracle-11g

I have an issue with oracle 11g installed on a Windows Server 2016.

When I create a new DB the hostname is always as the following image shows.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Eg4.png

However, my hostname isn't that at all, in fact it's a "proper" hostname.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUrAS.png

I've tried creating different databases and it always happens. I'm trying to set up Oracle Streams, and i'm afraid this might cause some isues.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this, just in case someone has the same issue and needs a fix.

What worked for me, was disable every network card except for the "main" one (AKA, the one that goes to the internet). Then reinstal Oracle 11g, create a listener and a database, and then I enabled the network adapters.

Got a proper hostname and everything seems to be working.